# How to separate all the keys and values and store in an array using shell script with jq parser

Tags: json, bash, shell, grep, jq

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
 "images1" : 
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
 "images2" : 
    {
      "size" : "29x30",
      "idiom" : "iphone2",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png2",
      "scale" : "22x"
    }
}
```

I will pass JSON object name as an input. So if I know "images1" is the object, then I need all the keys and values of that object to be stored in two separate arrays, so that I can make use of them in further processing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
jq ".$1 | { keys: keys_unsorted, values: [.[]] }"
```

where `$1` should provide the name of the item you want to address (note that this assume you're using this in a script. You will probably want to use fedorqui's alternative instead).

It will produce an object whose `keys` property will be an array of the keys of `$1` and `values` an array of the associated values :

```
$ echo '{
 "images1" :
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
 "images2" :
    {
      "size" : "29x30",
      "idiom" : "iphone2",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png2",
      "scale" : "22x"
    }
}' | jq ".images1 | { keys: keys_unsorted, values: [.[]] }"
{
  "keys": [
    "size",
    "idiom",
    "filename",
    "scale"
  ],
  "values": [
    "29x29",
    "iphone",
    "Icon-Small@2x.png",
    "2x"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Kudos Aaron..Your solution works for me..Thanks a lot